# b.on() is not a function jquery

Tags: jquery

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(main);

function main(){
    b = $('.buy-info').get(0);
    b.on();
};
```

I want to use `.on()` method but I'm getting the following error, it works fine with `.click()` method.
I'm using : jquery-3.3.1.js

> Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: b.on is not
> a function at main

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get(0)` returns the DOM element, while `.on()` is defined on the jQuery wrapper.

```
$(b).on(eventType, [childSelector,] handler);
```

will work, though...

---

Alternatively, you could:

```
$('.buy-info').eq(0).on(...)'
```

...or...

```
$('.buy-info').first().on(...);
```

---

As for `click()`, it does work on both, because it's defined as a method on both. The one on DOM is pretty basic. It triggers the `click` event on the DOM element, while the jQuery version can either trigger the click or define a click event listener, depending on parameters.